# Is it possible to write or change EXIF data of images saved to iPhone photo library

Tags: iphone, image-processing, exif, steganography

I would like to add some custom data to an image the user generates in my app, no more than 1kb tops. I could probably hide the data in the image, but I want to do this in a way that will resist resizing but not deliberate deletion of EXIF tags (say, for privacy reasons).

Is this possible using the current public SDK 3.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this might be helpful, though i've never used it before - [iphone-exif](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/)

Answer (score 0):

This could be very useful: PhotoshopFramework is one powerful library to manipulate images on Objective-C. This was developed to bring the same functionalities that Adobe Photoshop users are familiar. Examples: Set colors using RGB 0-255, apply blend filers, transformations...

Is open source, here is the project link: https://sourceforge.net/projects/photoshopframew/

Comment: You posted the exact same text on one of my other questions. Does your project allow editing of EXIF data? If so, how?